# Printing Rows Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have write a code and getting the values via jQuery and Ajax using the following code, the data comes fine but i could not populate the rows in my table. the looping is not work.

This is my table code in html

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Hospital Details</th>
                <th>Requested Product</th>
                <th>Units</th>
                <th>Patient Details</th>
                <th>Interval</th>
                <th>Requester</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="result">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

### This is my ajax script

```
<script>
    $.get("./../incomingRequestList.php", function(data, status){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        for($i=0; $i<obj.length; $i++){
            $response +=  "<tr><td>1</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
        }

        $('#result').html($response);
    });
</script>
```

How can i overcome this issue. I am unable to find out why its wrong.

Comment: Where're the variable declarations: `var $i` and `var $response = ""` ?

Comment: `$response` not defined

Comment: Yes I define $response = ""; great small mistake lots of time loss thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do it is:

```
<script>
    $.get("./../incomingRequestList.php", function(data, status){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        var response = '';
        for(i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
            response +=  "<tr><td>"+obj.number+"</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
        }

        $('#result').html(response);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Great Mistake :P)